# Python Converting numbers to words, using Recursive

Tags: python, recursion, numbers-to-words

My function recursively calls itself until it decodes every numbers. **rec_ntw**

**face_value_count** -> (Incremental variable) denotes ones, tens, hundreds and thousands
**face_value** -> (Dictionary) denotes the dictionary containing corresponding the word value for numbers.

**result** -> (String) Contains final result to return.

**teen** -> (Integer) to decode the teen numbers from eleven to ninteen

**number % 10** to get the last element

**number // 10** to remove the last element and pass it on to recursive the function.

```
def rec_ntw(number, face_value_count=0):
        result = ""
        teen = 0
        if number <= 0:
                if face_value_count == 0:
                        result = "Zero"
                print (result)
                #return result
        else:
                if face_value_count == 0:
                        result = (singleton[int(number % 10)])
                        teen = number % 10
                elif face_value_count == 1:
                        if number % 10 == 1:
                                result = (face_value[1][1][int(teen)]) + " "
                        else:
                                result = (face_value[int(face_value_count)][int(number % 10)]) + " " + result
                                teen = 0
                elif face_value_count == 2:
                        if number % 10 != 0:
                                result = (singleton[int(number % 10)] + " " + str(face_value[int(face_value_count)]) + " ") + result
                else:
                        result = (singleton[int(number % 10)] + " " + str(face_value[int(face_value_count)]) + " ") + result
                face_value_count += 1
                rec_ntw(number // 10, face_value_count)
```

Please review my code and lemme know how to write effectively.

Comment: seeing the definition of `face_value` would be a great addition to this post.

Comment: what is `singleton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your desired output? Your function has no return statements (other the one commented out), and the only print statement is in the `number <= 0` block. Have you run this function? Unless I'm missing something, it won't do anything if you input 0. And when you strip out the last digit, you don't actually store it anywhere, so it's just gone.

You seem to be doing double tabs for your indents, which makes it hard to read once you get several levels deep. Also, you can save yourself an indent level after the `number <= 0` block; since you have nothing but an `else` block after this, you can put a return at the end of the `if` block. Then you won't ever get to the `else` block unless the `if` condition is false, making the `else` redundant. So you can get rid of that and move everything in an indent level.

You don't show what face_value is, so it's hard to evaluate your code when it comes to that part.

Also, unless I'm misunderstanding, the `if number <= 0` block should be something like this:

```
if face_value_count == 0:
     result = "Zero"
     print (result)
     return(result)
return('negative '+rec_ntw(-number, face_value_count))
```

You could replace the `if else` blocks after the `number <= 0` block with a case statement.

Using recursion in this case is rather odd. The basic structure of your function is:

```
def f(x):
  #do action 1
  #do action 2
  #do action 3
```

But you're implementing it as:

```
def f(x,instruction_address):
   if instruction_address == 1:
       # do action 1
   if instruction_address == 2:
       # do action 2
   if instruction_address == 3:
       # do action 3
   f(x, instruction_address+1)
```

That's just ... really weird.

Consider the following code:

```
def numbers_to_words(number):
    numbers = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine',
              'ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen',
              'seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']
    tens_places = ['twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']
    if number <20:
        return(numbers[number])
    #print(number)
    if number%10 == 0:
        return(tens_places[number//10-2])
    return(tens_places[int(str(number)[0])-2]+'-'+numbers[int(str(number)[1])])
```

This turns any number from 0 to 99 to words, no recursion. It can easily be extended to -999 to 999, and a little more work would get it to, say, -10^33 to 10^33.